# Convert HTML to PDF in a .NetCoreApp

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

Im developing a function in a .NetCoreApp Ver 1.1. Ive been looking for a way to convert HTML to PDF and other similar questions here on Stack recommended https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp

But it seems it can be run in a .NetCoreApp. Are there any simple ways to convert HTML to PDF in a .NetCoreApp?

Comment: Did you tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRendererCore.PdfSharpCore ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in .Net Core:

https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

Comment: I tried it but the error message says: "NU1002 The dependency NReco.PdfGenerator 1.1.15 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1."

Comment: I use this one via nugget: NReco.PdfGenerator.LT

Comment: ...using VS2017 .net core 1.1.1 libraries

Comment: @IdkWhy I have purchased a license but looks like there is a free version.

Comment: This page has a free download link: https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx  ..maybe it is the generator that you need, have you tried?

Comment: ok, I see, maybe contact them see if there is one, I found the developer very helpful before.

Answer (score -1):

Nreco is nice, but today's free version (not LT, which is not free) is for .net core up to version 2.  I have netcore 3.1 and will upgrade to 5 soon, so I searched further yesterday. After trying few popular, I found: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HiQPdf.Free.NetCore/

What are it's PRO's:

1. It is lightweight, only 40 Mb. Others are minimum as twice bigger.
2. It has all in one package functionality. You don't need any additional packages or Qt libraries or something else.
3. There is a free version